# Docker for Windows breaks Virtual Box

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

I am very new to docker and I am following [Docker for Azure Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-4.3.1)

After installing for windows and running the powershell command I had Docker flash up with a request to turn on Hyper V

However, there was also a warning that Virtual Box VMs will not work

How can I get round this?

Comment: I think you’ll have to run docker machine instead, see e.g. https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/

Comment: yuk!  lol I was hoping to avoid command line stuff!!

Comment: You either use docker-machine and toolbox if you are looking for using VirtualBox VMs. If you don't care about running other VirtualBox VMs then you can use Docker for windows which uses HyperV. You can also use Hyperv to create additional VMs if you want. So your choice of which VM manager you would prefer

Comment: I already use Virtual Box VM for development of a totally different system. I would like to use the best and most recommend way of doing containers for my work with them but avoid a situation where I can't access the virtual machine for my other system. I think I may need a way to disable and enable hyper v? I can then disable it when i am working on my old system and turn it on when working on the new system

Comment: Disabling and re-enabling hyper-v requires a restart though so it may not be as optimal as you would like

Comment: I really don't mind restarting I won't be needing the virtual box vm much